# service for route parameter returning url without /

Tags: angular

I am using route parameter with activated route to redirect to another component on click of a link in an iterated list:

**show-students.component.html**

```
<table>
 <tr *ngFor="let f of studentsfromapi | slice:0:10">
      <td>{{f.userId}}</td>
      <td><a [routerLink]="['/student-details', f.id]">{{f.id}}</a></td>
      <td>{{f.title}}</td>
      <td>{{f.completed}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

  {path: 'home', component: ShowStudentsComponent },
  {path: 'student-details', component: studentDetailsComponent },
  {path: 'student-details/:id', component: studentDetailsComponent },
  {path: 'marks', component: MarksComponentComponent },
  {path: '', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch:'full' }

]
```

**student-http-serv.service.ts:**

```
getstudentDetailsHttpSrv(studentCode): Observable<IStudentHttp[]>{


  return this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos' + studentCode)
  .map((response:Response) =>  <IStudentHttp[]>response.json());
    }
```

**studentDetailscomponent.component.ts:**
this is the file in which the service is fired for displaying student details

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import{ StudentHttpServService } from '../show-students/student-http-serv.service';
    import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
    import {Inject} from '@angular/core';
    import {IStudentHttp} from '../show-students/servicehttp';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-classes-component',
//  templateUrl: './classes-component.component.html',
template: `
d<table>

  <tr *ngFor="let studtls of studentsDetailsfromapi">
<td>{{studtls.id}}</td>
<td>{{studtls.title}}</td>

  </tr>

</table>
`, 
styleUrls: ['./classes-component.component.css']
})
export class studentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  studentsDetailsfromapi:any;

  constructor(@Inject(StudentHttpServService) private __astudentHttpServService: StudentHttpServService, @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private _activatedroute: ActivatedRoute, @Inject(Router) private _router:Router) { 

   }


  ngOnInit() {

//this._StudentHttpServService.getstudentDetailsHttpSrv()

let studentCode = this._activatedroute.snapshot.params['id'];
 /* this.__astudentHttpServService.getstudentDetailsHttpSrv(studentCode).subscribe(

  (employeeData) =>{ this.studentsDetailsfromapi=employeeData; alert("this.studentsDetailsfromapi"+this.studentsDetailsfromapi)}

  )*/

  this.__astudentHttpServService.getstudentDetailsHttpSrv(studentCode).subscribe(

    (employeeData) =>{alert("hi"); this.studentsDetailsfromapi=employeeData}
  )

  }

}
```

the when i click on the id to display the student details page, the following error occurs:

[image]

so the issue is that the url that is coming as a result of following function:

```
let studentCode = this._activatedroute.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.__astudentHttpServService.getstudentDetailsHttpSrv(studentCode).subscribe(

        (employeeData) =>{alert("hi"); this.studentsDetailsfromapi=employeeData}
      )
```

should be : `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3 and not`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos3. so the problem is that '/' is not appending before `id` (or you can say `studentCode` ).

in **student-http-serv.service.ts**, i tried:

```
return this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos' + '/' + studentCode)
```

but it showed error.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + studentCode)` should work

Comment: i tried that too, but it showed an error:
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Not sure, but the variable you populated value is `studentsDetailsfromapi` and you have used `studentsfromapi` on HTML.. please fix the variable name typo and try

Comment: Actually studentsDetailsfromapi is component to which the routerParams is redirected on click of the id link.